# Check if a value exists in switch case statement

Tags: php

I have a switch case to display my php pages with id's like this:

```
<?php 
    
    $id = 1;

    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
    }
    
    switch ($id) {
        case 1: require_once 'home.php';
            break;
        case 2: require_once 'courseInfo.php';
            break;
        case 3: require_once 'aboutUs.html';
            break;
        case 4: require_once 'contacts.html';
            break;
        case 5: require_once 'accountDashboard.php';
            break;
        case 6: require_once 'accountCourses.php';
            break;
        case 7 : require_once 'studentLogin.php';
            break;
        case 8 : require_once 'applicationForm.php';
            break;
        case 9: require_once 'accountFiles.php';
            break;
        case 10: require_once 'accountCursoAulas.php';
            break;
        case 11: require_once 'event.php';
            break;
        case 12: require_once 'allEvents.php';
            break;
        default: require_once 'home.php';
            break;
    }
?>
```

I have an error page already and want to display it when a user types an id in the URL that is not in the switch case. I assume this is pretty easy but I can't seem to think or find it anywhere.

Comment: the default like your `default: require_once 'home.php';` usually for handling *"if it doesn't exists in the switch case"* case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And that's where the default case comes in, you could go like

```
<?php 

$id = 1;

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}

switch ($id) {
    case 1: require_once 'home.php';
        break;
    case 2: require_once 'courseInfo.php';
        break;
    case 3: require_once 'aboutUs.html';
        break;
    case 4: require_once 'contacts.html';
        break;
    case 5: require_once 'accountDashboard.php';
        break;
    case 6: require_once 'accountCourses.php';
        break;
    case 7 : require_once 'studentLogin.php';
        break;
    case 8 : require_once 'applicationForm.php';
        break;
    case 9: require_once 'accountFiles.php';
        break;
    case 10: require_once 'accountCursoAulas.php';
        break;
    case 11: require_once 'event.php';
        break;
    case 12: require_once 'allEvents.php';
        break;
    default: require_once 'errorPage.php'; //Since id didn't match any value
        break;
}
```

?>

Or you could just validate id if you know the range of values

```
<?php 

$id = 1;

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
}

if($id < 1 || $id > 12){
  require_once 'errorPage.php';
}else{
  switch ($id) {
    case 1: require_once 'home.php';
        break;
    case 2: require_once 'courseInfo.php';
        break;
    case 3: require_once 'aboutUs.html';
        break;
    case 4: require_once 'contacts.html';
        break;
    case 5: require_once 'accountDashboard.php';
        break;
    case 6: require_once 'accountCourses.php';
        break;
    case 7 : require_once 'studentLogin.php';
        break;
    case 8 : require_once 'applicationForm.php';
        break;
    case 9: require_once 'accountFiles.php';
        break;
    case 10: require_once 'accountCursoAulas.php';
        break;
    case 11: require_once 'event.php';
        break;
    case 12: require_once 'allEvents.php';
        break;
    default: require_once 'home.php';
        break;
  }
}
```

?>

Comment: I was sure i missed something easy... Well done